# Serial channel communication, what am i sending?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I created a c# program which sends and receives data by using serial port. Basically i send a data and display it on the other winform panel. Im new at this stuff and i have struggled with what am i sending behind it. What is happening  behind the data when im sending and receiving it? Can somebody please explain it?

Comment: What kind of device did you connect to the serial port of the computer? Or is it two computers connected by a serial cable?

Comment: Please add you sending and maybe even receiving code because based on your description we cant tell what you are doing

Comment: The question is not clear. Don't you know what you are sending? This is a bit odd.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.